# Make columns in data frame equal to median, mean, etc.? (R)

Tags: r

I have several rows of numerical data, each representing a different quantity or measurement. I'm supposed to make the columns equal to the means of the the different quantities, the IQRS of the different quantities, and the medians of the different quantities, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do that?

Comment: An example of input and output benefits everybody .

Comment: Input: data.frame(c(1, 3 , 5), c(1, 1, 2), c(256, 5, 4))

Comment: Output should be these as rows and then columns for each specified requirement (mean, median, etc.)

Comment: Your question is still totally unclear. Is `1 / 3 / 5` a row or a column? Essentially do you want `data.frame(a=c(1,3,5),b=c(1,1,2),c=c(256,5,4))` or `data.frame(a=c(1,1,256),b=c(3,1,5),c=c(5,2,4))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(1, 3 , 5), y=c(1, 1, 2), z=c(256, 5, 4))
```

Using dplyr/tidyr:

```
df1<-df%>%gather(var,val,x:z)%>%group_by(var)%>%summarise(max=max(val),min=min(val),avg=mean(val),median=median(val))
```

you can extend this to any number of summary stats.

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
    var   max   min       avg median
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1     x     5     1  3.000000      3
2     y     2     1  1.333333      1
3     z   256     4 88.333333      5
```